# Inclue one css class inside another css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have one css class having a property which calls another CSS class?

**Example:**

```
.redcolor {
    color:red;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    color: redcolor;
}
```

Comment: no it's only Less css

Answer (score 2):

No unless you are using SASS/LESS. You are stuck with giving everything "Red" as a normal class.

Answer (score 0):

No ! It is not possible in plain CSS but you can always use Some CSS Preprocessors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

**New Edit**: Okay I was searching about it and seems your problem can be solved without using pre Preocessor have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

**but**, let me clear this is experimental as per MDN can may not be compatible in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with SASS:

```
$bodyColor: #000;

body {
    color: $bodyColor;
}
```